# How to solve range slider zoom in ios

Tags: html, ios, responsive-design, rangeslider

I am using a range slider in my site. site [link](http://kapilpaul.com/matus) . click on the options on the header and you will see the range slider. its ion range slider jquery plugin.
Its working good on desktop and android. But in ios, when i click on the range slider to change its automatically zoom which I don't want. i just need it plain as desktop.

and one more problem in ios. the search bar border has no radius but it shows radius on ios.

Can you please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Search Bar Radius:

for (UIView *searchBarSubview in [mySearchBar subviews])

{

if ([searchBarSubview conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInputTraits)])

{
@try

{

[(UITextField *)searchBarSubview setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

}

@catch (NSException * e)

{

// ignore exception

}

}

}

Comment: hi thanks for comments. can you please tell me where should i implement this.

Comment: Check my another answer there i given easy one

Comment: bro thanks for the answer. i just fix the radius issue using this {-webkit-border-radius: 0px;-webkit-appearance: none;}

so can you please fix the zoom issue of range slider.

Comment: sure. no problem in android and desktop. but if i visit the site from ios the range slider(you will find it in dropdown option of search bar) first looks normal. when i click to change the values from slider it automatically zooms. thats the problem. and its lil bit weird.

Comment: you are viewing website through iOS using uiwebview right?

Comment: fine i got it , so you don`t developed your iPhone and android version right?

Answer (score 0):

(void)viewDidLoad

{

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UITextField *txfSearchField = [search valueForKey:@"_searchField"];

[txfSearchField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[txfSearchField setLeftView:UITextFieldViewModeNever];

[txfSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];

txfSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 8.0f;

txfSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;

txfSearchField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}